# Facebook stream publish to wall as App/Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

i wonder if it is possible to post to a users stream/wall by using stream_publish as a page or an app. Currently I've granted my app to stream_publish on my own wall. But when I post to my stream from the app the post is displayed like I would've posted it by myself instead of having the app posted it to my wall.

I want to have the post looks like the app posted it. I already used the uid-parameter in the stream_publish params and set it to the appId ... but the post still looks like an own post.

my code:

```
$postData = array(  $feed_dir = '/'.$fb_uid.'/feed/',
                        $method = 'POST',
                        $msg_body = array(  'access_token' => $arrUserData['access_token'], 
                                'message' => 'here goes the message',
                                'name' => '-name-',
                                'link' => 'http://some-url',
                                'description' => '-description-',
                                'actions' => ($actions),
                                'uid' => $iniHandler->getIniSetting('facebook.app.id')
                            )
                    );

                try {

                    $res = $facebook->api($feed_dir, $method, $msg_body);
                } 
                catch (Exception $e) {       
                    $err_str = $e->getMessage();

                }
```

Or is ther another way to post to a wall and let the post looks like a post by an app? My users can sign up for issues in my app and my app posts some news to the users wall ... thats my aim.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `manage_pages` permissions.  Once you have those, HTTP Get `me/accounts` and that will be a list of pages that the logged in user is admin of.  In that list will be a unique page access_token.  Use that token to http post a new wall/stream item.